# Convert PC PSU from VAC input to 12VDC

Tags: power-supply

I want to know if there is a simple way to take a common pc psu that takes 120/230vac as input and convert that input to 12 volt DC. Without inverters for use off-grid. This is a desktop gaming PC not a laptop with a ac/dc adapter

Also I am asking about electronics and circuitry contained in the psu not a tip or trick.

Comment: so after youtubing I am going to have to find flyback and rectifier bridge between the ac and dc sections. tapping into it there seems like a good idea unless someone has a better answer

Comment: 'flyback and rectifier bridge between the ac and dc sections' - this is describing an inverter, which you said you didn't want to use. You could build one ([example](https://m0ukd.com/homebrew/pic-controlled-500w-modified-sine-wave-inverter/)), or just buy a cheap inverter like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/High-power-12V-Boost-to-220V-500W-Modified-Sine-Wave-Car-Power-Inverter-/361937781215?hash=item54452c41df:g:0wIAAOSwTM5Y2N2G) and plug your power supply into it.

Comment: please read edited question

Comment: Please google for "atx power 12V input". But to answer your question: no there isn't. If you see this document http://www.onsemi.com/site/pdf/BoostingPowerSupply.pdf you will find the DC section is actually high voltage DC not 12V. As for cost, a desigh with 12V input is much cheaper to make, although the market volume of a conventional PSU will make it cheaper to buy.

Answer (score 2):

There's the extremely inefficient approach of using the 12V DC to supply an inverter that outputs 120 to 230V AC, then plug the power supply into that.

Or the more efficient approach of throwing the wrong power supply away, and getting a PSU that actually does what you need - probably one or more off-the-shelf DC/DC converters.

Comment: yes I know so no inverters as mentioned in the question . after market 12v psu's run 400usd for the wattage I need to operate the pc

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it is a 12 V output type you cut the lead off, throw everything else away, bare the ends and connect them to the 12 V battery observing the correct polarity.

If it's not a 12 V output then it is very unlikely that you can modify it as you wish.

Comment: And if its a PC PSU, there are probably tricks you need to make it start up; there's lots of info about that.

Comment: I would prefer to catch the connection in the box after AC conversion at the point where all 3.3 5 12 get their source

Comment: They don't usually work like that, the various outputs will probably be generated directly rather than from a common rail. At the kind of currents PCs use on 5V and 3.3V it would be very inefficient.

Comment: "after market 12v psu's run 400usd for the wattage I need to operate the pc" - _what_ wattage do you need? If you need 3.3V and 5V as well as 12V then your existing PSU is probably not suitable, but you _might_ be able to use part of it with a cheap DC/DC converter - depending on exactly what voltages and currents are required. Or there may be another solution that doesn't cost US$400 - but we can't advise you if we don't know what you need!